# Resize Entry with window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I am using Tkinter and I want my elements to resize when the window resizes (only horizontally)

I tried sticking to `W+E` but apparently this only works when the window is created but not when it's resized.

Minimal example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Label, StringVar, W, E, N, S

class Test:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Variable definitions
        self.master = master
        self.var1 = StringVar()

        # Element definitions
        self.label1 = Label(text="Dummy test")
        self.entry1 = Entry(master, textvariable=self.var1)

        # Grid placement
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E)

root = Tk()
Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Original window when program is executed:

[image]

When I resize, I want the Entry to grow and shrink with the window
[image]

Comment: You need to use `grid_columnconfigure(...)` like in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I saw it and worked, thanks. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't think you should, it is well asked.

Comment: Why people downvote? If it's a duplicate it will be closed when flagged, no need to downvote!